# How to Remove "/wp" from main domain?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a domain which has a very old build site being shown on url typing. I have made a new one on wordpress but it is getting showed through "maindomain/wp" url and I don't know how can i solve this issue. Guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: U mean the websites url contain " /wp "  ?

Comment: hey @eli ....yes the url contained /wp. i found out that the site was getting created in the sub directory so i removed that directory and issue was solved... i appreciate your concern!